# Cant get in if statement in jsp file

Tags: java, mysql, database, jsp, jdbc

I'm developing a login page where members doing login and signup.I have trouble when I compare username and password with the user's data in database table. This piece of code throws this exception but I can't understand what's going wrong.
the server throws this message:

> javax.servlet.ServletException: java.sql.SQLException: Before start of result set

```
String search_in ="select USERNAME,PASSWORD from USERS";
ResultSet search_result= myStatement.executeQuery( search_in );



while( search_result.next() ){
a[i] = search_result.getString("USERNAME");
b[i] = search_result.getString("PASSWORD");


//new_username and  new_password are form input parameters
if( a[i].equals(new_username) && b[i].equals(new_password) ){
    out.println("in if statement<br>");
    found = true;
    break;
    }
i++;
}
```

Comment: Describe your db table as well

Comment: post the complete exception stack

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error msg is sufficient for the root cause..!!

> javax.servlet.ServletException: java.sql.SQLException: Before start of result set

This happens if we try to access the row which is not indexed by our `resultSet` cursor. What's that???

When we fire a `select` query, in result we can get multiple rows or single row or no row at all (result depends on your query and data).

These rows gets stored in the `resultSet` instance.

To access these row, we can iterate loop over them by `resultSet.next()` (or by any other ways..). As you used while loop over `.next()` function, I'm considering the same.

So, this `next()` function actually moves the cursor to next row, and initially it points one index before the actual result row, meaning, it indexes at `-1` value, so as soon as we fall in while loop, the `resultSet.next()` function moves the cursor to one position ahead, i.e. for the first time it will point to actual row at position `0` and so on until there is nothing left to iterate.

The error, you mention is because of the cursor is pointing at `-1` initially, and when it tries to iterate (i.e moving to really first row) it fails because no row is returned from that query and hence the error says `before the start of ResultSet`.

I hope it clears your perception about `resultSet` and gives you idea about stuffs happening behind the scene.

So, suggestion for your problem would be, try checking/changing your query or see in database, if it actually contains any such row that should be returned on that query or not.

Comment: If i understand you mean that maybe the query or database has a problem?but if print the a[i] and b[i] it returns me the datas as i insert them in table

Comment: Alright..!! So you are getting values of `a[i]` & `b[i]` in the same code block you posted or in some other page?? I mean how did you come to know it's values??

Comment: And I'm just guessing.., are you trying to validate user's login with above approach??

Comment: get the values of a[i] and b[i] inside the while loop because  i printed the to test, but when i compare with the form values in the if statement it doesnt do something

Comment: i have 2 records just for testing the parameters that i insert to the form are the first record

Comment: Are you sure that `new_username` & `new_password` exactly matches with at least one record, I mean, the spacing and casing too..!!

Comment: Also see my new answer, I kept old one as it is for those who need to understand the root cause of the above error.!!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of fetching all the records from database and comparing values in your 
 application code, I would suggest you to ask database to give you the records according to your conditions.

To do this, change your query and code like below..

```
String search_in ="select USERNAME,PASSWORD from USERS where USERNAME = ? AND PASSWORD = ?";
myStatement.setString(1, new_username); // assuming your column is varchar or text
myStatement.setString(2, new_password); // assuming your column is varchar or text
ResultSet search_result= myStatement.executeQuery( search_in );

if( search_result.next() ){
   out.println("in if statement<br>");
    found = true;
}
```

Comment: I found it.The  problem was not at the checking for the data records but was at another if statement that was after found==true.Thanks for your help!

Comment: please consider up voting..!!